# What is the least amount of network traffic needed to update a git repo?

Tags: python, git

## git is slow, let's automate

The context is that I would like to write a script that updates ~150 git repositories. Gitlab/hub is almost an order of magnitude slower over the network compared to our earlier subversion installation, e.g.:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\lib\examradar> python -c "import time;start=time.time();import os;os.system('svn up');print time.time() - start"
Updating '.':
At revision 31294.
0.559000015259

(dev) go|c:\srv\lib\code\dkrepo> python -c "import time;start=time.time();import os;os.system('git pull');print time.time() - start"
Already up to date.
Current branch master is up to date.
4.31999993324
```

ie. 150 svn repos will at least take 84 seconds, while 150 git repos will take over 10 minutes(!)
(running the same commands in ubuntu on wsl on win10 gives 0.48secs and 1.52secs -- go figure ;-)

With a script we can do all "easy" updates in parallel and get the git-case down to ~100 seconds. Unfortunately, we're running into timeouts (very often when doing `git rev-parse @{u}`), so I'm looking for the most effective way to update a git repo and be kind to the git servers.

I'm open to "cheating" e.g. if there is a way of knowing (with high probability), outside of git, that a repo doesn't need to be updated (webhooks?, background fetch-daemons?)

Messing up a repo is very disruptive, so it should bail if pulling would create a merge conflict.

## current code

I'm using the python invoke package to make calling commands easier. I'll be happy with answers that only uses raw git commands too. Here is what I have so far...

First a convenience function that prints the command being ran, and its output, and returns the output as a string:

```
from invoke import task

def runner(c):
    return lambda cmd: c.run(cmd, hide=False, echo=True).stdout.strip()
```

then a task/function to get the repo status. I believe only `git fetch` and git rev-parse @{u}` touches the network(?):

```
@task
def get_status(c, wc):
    """Return a set containing the strings

          local-clean     if there are no local changes
          local-dirty     if there are local changes
          untracked       if there are files that haven't been added to git
          remote-change   if upstream has changed
          local-change    if there are local committed (but not pushed) changes
          diverged        if local and upstream have diverged

    """
    run = runner(c)

    with c.cd(wc):
        status = []
        porcelain = run('git status --porcelain')
        if porcelain == "":
            status.append('local-clean')
        else:
            status.append('local-dirty')
        untracked = run('git ls-files --others --exclude-standard')
        if untracked:
            status.append('untracked')
        run('git fetch')    # only interested in current branch so not using `git remote update`
        local = run('git rev-parse @')  # get local hash
        try:
            remote = run('git rev-parse @{u}')  # get upstream hash
        except:
            remote = local  # repo doesn't have an upstream
        if local != remote:
            base = run('git merge-base @ @{u}')  # common ancestor
            if local == base:
                status.append('remote-change')
            elif remote == base:
                status.append('local-change')
            else:
                status.append('diverged')

    print("STATUS:", status)
    return set(status)
```

on an up-to-date repo this prints:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\tstgitup> inv get-status \srv\lib\core\ttcal
cd \srv\lib\core\ttcal && git status --porcelain
cd \srv\lib\core\ttcal && git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
cd \srv\lib\core\ttcal && git fetch
cd \srv\lib\core\ttcal && git rev-parse @
eb17f1a9723c992b265b9dce0ffb85274e956538
cd \srv\lib\core\ttcal && git rev-parse @{u}
eb17f1a9723c992b265b9dce0ffb85274e956538
STATUS: ['local-clean']
```

from the status I generate an update policy (see below for the semantics):

```
def update_policy(status):
    policy = None

    if 'diverged' in status or 'untracked' in status:
        policy = 'BAIL'
    elif 'local-dirty' in status:           # local uncommitted changes
        if 'remote-change' in status:       # remote changes
            if 'local-change' in status:    # local committed changes
                policy = 'BAIL'
            else:
                policy = 'STASH'  # local uncommitted changes and remote changes
        else:
            policy = 'NOOP'     # local uncommitted changes, no remote changes
    elif 'remote-change' in status:
        if 'local-change' in status and 'local-clean' in status:
            policy = 'PULL'     # remote changes and local committed changes
        elif 'local-dirty' in status:
            policy = 'STASH'    # remote changes and local uncommitted changes
        else:
            policy = 'PULL'     # remote change, no local changes
    elif 'local-change' in status:
        if 'remote-change' in status:
            policy = 'PULL'     # local committed changes and remote changes
        else:
            policy = 'NOOP'     # no remote changes
    else:
        policy = 'NOOP'  # no local/remote changes, no untracked files.
    return policy
```

and finally, a `gitup` command that will do the update:

```
@task
def gitup(c, wc):
    run = runner(c)
    status = get_status(c, wc)
    policy = update_policy(status)
    print("UPDATE:POLICY:", policy)

    if policy == 'BAIL':
        print("don't know what to do, bailing..")
    elif policy == 'NOOP':
        print("nothing to do..")
    elif policy == 'PULL':
        # run('git pull')
        print("RUN: git merge FETCH_HEAD")  # we've already done a `git fetch` so don't call `git pull`
    elif policy == 'STASH':
        # print("RUN: git stash clear")  #..?
        print("RUN: git stash push")
        print("RUN: git merge FETCH_HEAD")
        print("RUN: git stash pop -q")
    else:
        print("UNKNOWN POLICY:", policy)
```

## status/policies/actions

on a repo with a local uncommitted change:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\tstgitup> inv gitup \srv\lib\almanac
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git status --porcelain
 M .gitignore
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git fetch
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git rev-parse @
e23bfd8a03432ca02cfb0e31bb229d2bb53dfc4f
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git rev-parse @{u}
e23bfd8a03432ca02cfb0e31bb229d2bb53dfc4f
STATUS: ['local-dirty']
UPDATE:POLICY: NOOP
nothing to do..
```

checking the file in

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\tstgitup> pushd \srv\lib\almanac && git commit -am "update gitignore" && popd
[master 21a727f] update gitignore
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

gives

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\tstgitup> inv gitup \srv\lib\almanac
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git status --porcelain
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git fetch
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git rev-parse @
21a727fd31357e585f4de6f6af6d3fef87da4dee
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git rev-parse @{u}
e23bfd8a03432ca02cfb0e31bb229d2bb53dfc4f
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git merge-base @ @{u}
e23bfd8a03432ca02cfb0e31bb229d2bb53dfc4f
STATUS: ['local-clean', 'local-change']
UPDATE:POLICY: NOOP
nothing to do..
```

pushing the change:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\tstgitup> pushd \srv\lib\almanac && git push && popd
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 285 bytes | 285.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://gitlab.com/norsktest/almanac.git
   e23bfd8..21a727f  master -> master

(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\tstgitup> inv gitup \srv\lib\almanac
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git status --porcelain
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git fetch
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git rev-parse @
21a727fd31357e585f4de6f6af6d3fef87da4dee
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git rev-parse @{u}
21a727fd31357e585f4de6f6af6d3fef87da4dee
STATUS: ['local-clean']
UPDATE:POLICY: NOOP
nothing to do..
```

after a change to upstream:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\tstgitup> inv gitup \srv\lib\almanac
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git status --porcelain
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git fetch
From https://gitlab.com/norsktest/almanac
   21a727f..1f0c065  master     -> origin/master
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git rev-parse @
21a727fd31357e585f4de6f6af6d3fef87da4dee
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git rev-parse @{u}
1f0c06576ee6eb2deb159f5d6d4b54c14867ca3a
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git merge-base @ @{u}
21a727fd31357e585f4de6f6af6d3fef87da4dee
STATUS: ['local-clean', 'remote-change']
UPDATE:POLICY: PULL
RUN: git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

changing an existing file:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\tstgitup> echo foobar >> \srv\lib\almanac\.gitignore

(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\tstgitup> inv gitup \srv\lib\almanac
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git status --porcelain
 M .gitignore
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git fetch
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git rev-parse @
21a727fd31357e585f4de6f6af6d3fef87da4dee
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git rev-parse @{u}
1f0c06576ee6eb2deb159f5d6d4b54c14867ca3a
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git merge-base @ @{u}
21a727fd31357e585f4de6f6af6d3fef87da4dee
STATUS: ['local-dirty', 'remote-change']
UPDATE:POLICY: STASH
RUN: git stash push
RUN: git merge FETCH_HEAD
RUN: git stash pop -q
```

..and finally(?) adding a new untracked file:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\tstgitup> touch \srv\lib\almanac\foo.bar

(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\tstgitup> inv gitup \srv\lib\almanac
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git status --porcelain
 M .gitignore
?? foo.bar
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
foo.bar
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git fetch
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git rev-parse @
21a727fd31357e585f4de6f6af6d3fef87da4dee
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git rev-parse @{u}
1f0c06576ee6eb2deb159f5d6d4b54c14867ca3a
cd \srv\lib\almanac && git merge-base @ @{u}
21a727fd31357e585f4de6f6af6d3fef87da4dee
STATUS: ['local-dirty', 'untracked', 'remote-change']
UPDATE:POLICY: BAIL
don't know what to do, bailing..
```

Comment: "Unfortunately, we're running into timeouts (very often when doing git rev-parse @{u})" - this operation runs locally, without going over the network. You should not have a timeout here.

Comment: On the other hand, `git fetch` does reach out to another Git, bring over any new commits, and (last) update the remote-tracking names (`origin/*`) so here you might want a timeout to indicate "couldn't reach or complete transaction with other Git in whatever time we deem maximum". (At a previous job I wrote an "update multiple local cached repos in parallel" thing, which was somewhat useful.)

Comment: I've implemented an automatic retry of the command that times out, and while that seems to be working it feels very hackish..

Comment: If you're only interested in the current branch, then you'll do well to set the `protocol.version` option to 2 and perform a fetch only for the current branch.  That will speed things up a lot if there are many refs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to ask git to sync the complete repository histories, it's just usually most convenient and cheap enough to do it while you're there anyway. Try asking svn and git to do the same thing before comparing them.  `svn up` only cares about the current tip and doesn't do any checking at all for the rest.

```
$ time git ls-remote git://github.com/torvalds/linux refs/heads/master
6e8ba0098e241a5425f7aa6d950a5a00c44c9781        refs/heads/master

real    0m0.536s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.007s
$
```

No surprise here, checking a single remote tip takes about the same time with svn and git.

Your current branch's short name is `git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD` (or else you're not on a branch).

So a much closer equivalent for what your svn up is doing would be

```
if branch=`git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD` && 
    remote=`git config branch.$branch.remote` &&
    merge=`git config branch.$branch.merge` &&
    upstreamtip=`git ls-remote $remote $merge | cut -f1` &&
    test $upstreamtip != `git rev-parse @{u}`
        then git pull $remote $merge
fi
```